# python setup.py how to add all sources file into compile?

Tags: python, cython

```
extensions = [Extension(name="xxx", 
    sources=
    ['xxx.pyx',
     '/home/sample/c001.c',
     ...
     '/home/sample/c100.c',
    ],
    language='c',
    extra_compile_args = ['-std=gnu11'],
    extra_link_args=['-std=gnu11'],
                    )]

setup(
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)
```

Question> Is there a syntax that I can use to include all source files within a given directory?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `/home/sample/*.c`? This is just from memory but it is worth trying.

Comment: That certainly works for pyx files. If it turns out not to work for .c files it'd be easy use os.path to find the files

Comment: Are the C codes just to be wrapped by pyx? If it is, I think the simplest way is adding special comments in the pyx sources for setuptools, eg:`# distutils: sources="..."` ，then in `setup`, just cythonize all pyx files(one can use `os.walk` to find all of them), the external c sources will be handled automatically.

Comment: @oz1, May you please give an example?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, I tried and it doesn't work. The error message is similar as *.c: No such file or directory

Comment: ok. then: `from glob import glob` at the top then `sources = glob('path/to/files/*.c')` and `sources.append('xxx.pyx')`. glob is a "wildcard pattern matcher" that works similarly to `ls path/to/files/*.c`